# LINQtoSQL Data not Inserting into SQL Combact Edition

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my LINQ INSERTS not persisting in SQL Server CE 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343816/why-are-my-linq-inserts-not-persisting-in-sql-server-ce-3-5)

I have a local database "Database1.sdf" and i'm trying to insert data into the table "User" using LinqToSql.

```
    public void DBTest()
    {
        string con = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf";
        Database1 db = new Database1(con);
        User user=new User();
        user.ID=3;
        user.Name="testdata";
        db.User.InsertOnSubmit(user);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        var q = from t in db.User
                select t;
        foreach (var t in q)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(t.Name);
        }
    }
```

The select query after the insertion works fine and shows the result, but the database is not updated. If i go and check the table manually it is empty. If i run the program again it doesn't throw any exception of primary key violation.

[image: Table Schema]

Thanks

Comment: You set the PK manually? Not by identity with auto-increment?

Comment: Got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343816/why-are-my-linq-inserts-not-persisting-in-sql-server-ce-3-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Why are my LINQ INSERTS not persisting in SQL Server CE 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343816/why-are-my-linq-inserts-not-persisting-in-sql-server-ce-3-5)